# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = open('sevi.txt', 'wb')
    content = filename.write("Cats are smarter than dogs")
    for line in content.read(): 
        match = re.findall('[A-Z]+', line)
        print match
    filename.close()
```

I am new to python. I am just opening a file and writing some text into it. Later reading the content find all the characters in it by using regular expression.  but I am getting the error as 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'. if I use readlines also, I am getting the error.

Comment: TIP: try printing content and see

Comment: `filename.write()` returns `None` in Python 2. Did you mean to use `filename.read()` instead? You'll need to open the file in `w+` mode to be able to do that though.

Comment: i am getting the error as None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\mud.txt", line 12, in <module>
    for line in content.read():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: FWIW, the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function takes a file name string and returns a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), so calling that file object `filename` is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 6):

The `file.write()` method returns `None` in Python 2 (in Python 3 it returns the number of bytes written, for a binary file).

If you want to both write and read with the same file you'll need to open that file in `w+` mode, and *seek back* to put the file position back to the start:

```
with open('sevi.txt', 'w+b') as fileobj:
    fileobj.write("Cats are smarter than dogs")
    fileobj.seek(0)  # move back to the start
    for line in fileobj: 
        match = re.findall('[A-Z]+', line)
        print match
```

Note that looping over the file object can be done directly, producing individual lines.

I made two other changes: I renamed your variable to `fileobj`; you have a file object, not just the name of the file here. And I used the file object as a context manager, so that it is closed automatically even if any errors occur in the block.

Comment: but it is printing as : ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z']
['Z']
['X', 'P', 'R', 'C', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'C']
['B', 'E', 'BCDEFGHIH', 'NOPQRSTUK', 'Z', 'N', 'Q', 'T', 'W', 'Z', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R']
['I']
['V', 'E', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'P', 'Y', 'S', 'C']

Comment: @sam: Yes, isn't that what you expected? You didn't tell us anything about what you were trying to do.

Comment: @sam: your `find_all()` call finds all groups of uppercase letters and returns a list of them. So if your text includes only individual `Z` initials, that's what you get returned.

Comment: if i want to search for specifi word in my .txt (example - smarter). then what should i do ? . If i want to find only letters within my .txt.

Comment: @sam: that's an entirely new problem, separate from your question, and too broad to answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

`filename.write("Cats are smarter than dogs")` is the function that returns `None` type like every function in Python if it's not specified otherwise with a `return` statement. So the value of the variable `content` is `None` and You are trying to read from that. Try `filename.read()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 

ofile = open('sevi.txt', 'r+')

ofile.write("Cats are smarter than dogs")

ofile.seek(0)

data = ofile.read()

upper = re.findall(r'[A-Z]', data)

print upper

lower = re.findall(r'[a-z]', data)

print lower

ofile.close()
```